# How to make my drawing in a frame depends in the window resolution in wxwidgets C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wxwidgets

[enter image description here][1]lately i want to developed an electrical GUI it's a sort of a supervion plateform, but i still have some problems with the window resolution. When the window get bigger my drawing stay in the same coordinates, can someone help me to fix this .
Thanks.

Comment: It looks as though your image didn't get included properly. Can you try re-adding it so we can see the issue you're having?

Comment: do you have any way of retrieving the resolution? if so you could calculate the proper scaling

Answer (score 0):

Handling different screen resolutions is well handled (but still not perfect) in wxWidgets.

For your own drawings done with [wxDC](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_d_c.html) methods it's just a matter of setting the right origin and scale.

Some useful classes: [wxDisplay](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_display.html) , [wxDisplaySizeMM](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__gdi.html#ga964bb139750337d8e578450f88b6e97b) and wxWindow methods such as [FromDPI](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#aa934a31552633c076a87bca1100b0dc5)

Dealing with different screen resolutions means different text font sizes, which implies different control sizes. wxWidgets uses default OS native sizes. So the first rule is **don't use hard coded pixels values**, prefer [dialog units](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#acb6787b6c3c314f9e015658a89ad0265) and [sizers](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_sizer.html).

Also, on Windows you need a **manifest** with special command for [DPI handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266(v=vs.85).aspx). The manifest may hold a command like

```
<asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
     <dpiAware>true/pm</dpiAware>
</asmv3:windowsSettings>
```

Automatic Bitmaps sizes is the part where wxWidgets is not perfect yet. Anyhow with the above functions you are able to tell the size needed and resize (or use a different image) the bitmap on your own.

Comment: Thanks Ripi2 for your answer, but how can i set the right origin for example if i would make the origin(weight/2 , height/2) how cani coding it in wxwidgets. It will be great if you give me an example of that.

Comment: In your wxWidgets dir you find "samples/display" and "samples/drawing". Specially in "drawing" sample look for `Origin` and `Scale` subwords.